# Creating image data URI with proper format

Tags: html-email

I am sending html emails in php.I want to embed images so that images can be viewed directly
i used base64 encoding but it is not working as gmail is not supporting it.

But i received one email and it has image url in this format:

?ui=2&ik=f9790f3715&view=att&th=146e7afa75b55a47&attid=0.2&disp=emb&realattid=10bf591ea0437383_0.1&zw&atsh=1

and it was displayed directly. how is this working? any help please

Answer (score 2):

These are embedded images. You send an image as an attachment and then use it in your `img` element like: `<img src="cid:yourimage.png">`. Gmail transforms the "cid" link to its internal file storage link and that's why it gives `<img src="?ui=2&ik=...">` element.

This is one of two common ways to have images within email.

The other way is to keep images in your hosting and send `img` elements with external links: `<img src="http://yourdomain.com/yourimage.png">`
I strongly recommend to use the second approach especially if you expect to have a lot of images in your email. I had [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975951/gmail-doesnt-display-some-of-embedded-images) with attached images display on Gmail which I couldn't solve.

Comment: Thank you for explaining for how many images it is is better to use?

Comment: For more than 5 images per email I would use external file storage.

Comment: i am creating newsletter template some time it has more images if it has more images than 5 then i will not use embed images right ? thanks allot for helping